# Flutter App - ERROR, Xcode **BUILD FAILED**

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build

Here's my terminal output:
I have tried to update Xcode but i still get the same error. When i run flutter -doctor v it passes all cases, and theres a check-mark in every section. I have tried to build with AndroidStudio and then from the terminal and in both cases got the same error. AndroidStudio built with Nexus 6 API works fine, just having troubles with iOS building

```
~/Doc/FlutterLearn ❯  cd first_app                                 Py anaconda3
~/Doc/F/first_app ❯ c                                              Py anaconda3
~/Doc/F/first_app ❯ flutter run                                    Py anaconda3
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           5.6s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         5.0s
Xcode build done.                                           12.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
    n.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
    n.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:109:12: error: attributes may not be specified
    on a category
    @interface NSArray<ObjectType> (NSArrayDiffing)
               ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
    n.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:196:12: error: attributes may not be specified
    on a category
    @interface NSMutableArray<ObjectType> (NSMutableArrayDiffing)
               ^
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
    n.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:48:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
    n.framework/Headers/NSKeyValueCoding.h:8:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
    n.framework/Headers/NSOrderedSet.h:112:12: error: attributes may not be
    specified on a category
    @interface NSOrderedSet<ObjectType> (NSOrderedSetDiffing)
               ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
    n.framework/Headers/NSOrderedSet.h:187:12: error: attributes may not be
    specified on a category
    @interface NSMutableOrderedSet<ObjectType> (NSMutableOrderedSetDiffing)
               ^
    4 errors generated.
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIView.h:10:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCor
    e.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCor
    e.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:10:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCor
    e.framework/Headers/CATransform3D.h:12:9: fatal error: could not build
    module 'Foundation'
    #import <Foundation/NSValue.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIView.h:10:
    While building module 'OpenGLES' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCor
    e.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:7:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.
    framework/Headers/EAGLDrawable.h:8:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.
    framework/Headers/EAGL.h:8:10: fatal error: could not build module
    'Foundation'
    #include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     ~~~~~~~~^
    1 error generated.
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIView.h:10:
    While building module 'Metal' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCor
    e.framework/Headers/CAMetalLayer.h:7:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.fra
    mework/Headers/Metal.h:9:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.fra
    mework/Headers/MTLTypes.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module
    'Foundation'
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIView.h:10:
    While building module 'Metal' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCor
    e.framework/Headers/CAMetalLayer.h:7:
    While building module 'IOSurface' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.fra
    mework/Headers/MTLTexture.h:15:
    In file included from <module-includes>:3:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface
    .framework/Headers/IOSurfaceObjC.h:15:9: fatal error: could not build module
    'Foundation'
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    1 error generated.
    2 errors generated.
    4 errors generated.
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'CoreImage' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIColor.h:13:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage
    .framework/Headers/CoreImage.h:9:9: fatal error: could not build module
    'Foundation'
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'CoreImage' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIColor.h:13:
    While building module 'CoreVideo' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage
    .framework/Headers/CIImage.h:10:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo
    .framework/Headers/CoreVideo.h:29:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo
    .framework/Headers/CVPixelBuffer.h:462:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo
    .framework/Headers/CVPixelBufferIOSurface.h:26:10: fatal error: could not
    build module 'IOSurface'
    #include <IOSurface/IOSurfaceRef.h>
     ~~~~~~~~^
    1 error generated.
    2 errors generated.
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'FileProvider' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/NSFileProviderExtension.h:15:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvi
    der.framework/Headers/FileProvider.h:15:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvi
    der.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderDomain.h:8:9: fatal error: could not
    build module 'Foundation'
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    1 error generated.
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    While building module 'UserNotifications' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UNNotificationResponse+UIKitAdditions.h:10:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotif
    ications.framework/Headers/UserNotifications.h:8:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotif
    ications.framework/Headers/NSString+UserNotifications.h:8:9: fatal error:
    could not build module 'Foundation'
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    1 error generated.
    13 errors generated.
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/Flutter.h:54:
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module
    'UIKit'
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:
    While building module 'CoreMedia' imported from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
    Headers/FlutterTexture.h:8:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia
    .framework/Headers/CoreMedia.h:15:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia
    .framework/Headers/CMFormatDescription.h:29:10: fatal error: could not build
    module 'CoreVideo'
    #include <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
     ~~~~~~~~^
    1 error generated.
    15 errors generated.
    In file included from
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.m:5:
    /Users/snak3/Documents/FlutterLearn/first_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegi
    strant.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Flutter'
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    16 errors generated.
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build
    description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
~/Doc/F/first_app ❯  

                                 took 24s Py anaconda3
```

Here's the output from flutter doctor :

```
~ ❯ flutter doctor -v                                                                  Py anaconda3
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/snak3/flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (3 months ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/snak3/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 41.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761

[✓] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.6.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 8 • EB666770-13C5-4CE6-B24A-657C875939A7 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-0 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

**EDIT**:
I have found a way to make it work momentarily. I open Xcode and I build it it there and the Simulator runs, i then close Xcode and have the Simulator and build my app with VSCode. But how would I fix the terminal command errors?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end? If yes, it would be good to post it here in case others are facing a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (different errors, but all were about imports).

I managed to fix it eventually by upgrading `cocoapods` and `cocoapods-core` from version `1.9.3` to `1.10`.

Hope this may help someone else facing the same issue.